# Meteorjs I need a second page

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm playing with meteorjs and I get the idea behind it and the app that would benefit from such a tool. I'm making one myself while learning but I need a 2nd page. A 2nd page with it's own css and javascript and logic; completely separated from the main one. It's like 2 apps but sharing the same database with the same sessions.

Any ideas?

Comment: "a 2nd page... completely separated from the main one". It's not completely separated if it's sharing the same session.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use [router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router). You'll need to install [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/) in order to use it.

Comment: using router still makes meteor add every other javascript and css in the project. That's a client router not a server router to separate some logic.

Comment: It can also act as a server side router, keep in mind by wanting no js/css files you wont have all the meteor capabilities

Comment: I'm talking about my own js/css files. I don't want jquery for `route X` for example because in `route X` I need a clean and fast page with just the basic stuff meteor needs to function. Right now meteor adds to all pages no matter what route it is everything it finds which is too much and highly unneeded for `page X`. Think about the meteor website and docs.meteor.

Comment: I think I may need 2 meteor apps that share the same `MONGO_URL` am I right?

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea Have you tried a server-side router which just returns a static .HTML file that manually includes the relevant CSS and JS files in its `<head>` tag?